# Angular data binding not updating correct model scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform

having some inheritance issues (hopefully) on a scope object *userNotify*.

AccountCtrl handles user account data viewing and updating, data is coming from Parse.com db via *UserService* service.

```
.controller('AccountCtrl', [
    '$state', '$scope', 'UserService',
    function ($state, $scope, UserService) {

        UserService.currentUser().then(function (_user) {
            $scope.user = _user;
            notification = _user.get('days');
            $scope.userNotify = {days: notification};
        });

        $scope.updateUser = function (_user) {
            days = $scope.userNotify.days;
            // days is logged with the correct value (if the user changed)
            // but the db record is updated with the initial value not the new one.
            // tested this by changing days to a random number.
            console.log(days);
            _user.set('days', days);
            _user.save();
        }

}])
```

Data is displayed in the view and the *updateUser* function should update the user data in Parse db.

```
  <div ng-controller="AccountCtrl">
        <select ng-model="$parent.userNotify.days">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
        </select>
        <a ng-click="updateUser($parent.user)">Save</a>
  </div>
```

When *_user.set* is called in *updateUser* function, *$scope.userNotify.days* has the old value from the db, and thus updates with the same value, and not the new one the user selected.
Even though the *console.log(days)* displays the correct new value.

Have also tried removing *$parent* and working with primitive types.

Here is the UserService, which returns a Promise:

```
    .service('UserService', ['$q', 'ParseConfiguration',
        function ($q, ParseConfiguration) {

            return {
                /**
                 * @param _parseInitUser
                 * @returns {Promise}
                 */
                currentUser: function (_parseInitUser) {

                    _parseInitUser = Parse.User.current();

                    if (!_parseInitUser) {
                        return $q.reject({error: "noUser"});
                    } else {
                        return $q.when(_parseInitUser);
                    }
                }
            }
        }]);
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is the proper date being saved into the db?

Comment: It might not be related but you should use the `var` statement to avoid creating variables in the global scope. Like `var notification = ...` and `var days = ...`;

Comment: I did use `var` at no effect.
If I use a random number, it gets saved to the db
`_user.set('days', 15);`

This means the db set is working, the value though is not updated from the view in the `updateUser` function.

Comment: Was also considering using ng-change with another model or $watch, should this be necessary here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this as the snippet in the html

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
  <ion-view>
    <label class="item item-input item-select">
      {{currentSelection.value}}
      <select ng-model="currentSelection" ng-options="day as day.value for day in days track by day.value" style="width: 30px">
      </select>
    </label>
    <a class="button" ng-click="updateUser($parent.user)">Save</a>
  </ion-view>
</body>
```

this is the javascript code

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic'])
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.currentSelection = {};
    $scope.currentSelection.value = 1;

    $scope.days = [
      { value: 1 }, 
      { value: 2 }, 
      { value: 3 }
    ];
    $scope.updateUser = function() {
      days = $scope.currentSelection;
      alert(JSON.stringify(days));
    }
  }]);
```

Not sure why you are messing with `$parent` to get access to the user? there is only one current user and Parse provides a function to give you access to it throughout the application.

```
$scope.updateUser = function() {
  UserService.currentUser().then(function (_user) {
    return _user.save({days:daysValue});
  }).then(function(_updatedUser){
    console.log(_updatedUser);
  }, function(_error) {
    console.log(_error);
  });
};
```

Comment: This still returns the initial value from Parse, even though it updates the view when I change the select.

I am using `$scope.currentSelection.value = _user.get('days');` to set the initial select value

Comment: Thanks for your help, I got it working, see below answer.

Comment: there simply is not enough code here to understand your issue... as I stated, you should not need the parent scope at all see edits above

Answer (score 0):

I have got it working by passing the days from the view into the `updateUser` function.

In the view:

`<a ng-click="updateUser(user,userNotify.days)">Save</a>`

In the controller:

`$scope.updateUser = function (_user,days) { console.log(days); }`